# JQuery: Get the value of an input after the user has typed a value into it

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to resize dinamically an `iFrame` using Jquery.

There is an `input` in which the user sets the desired width and then I want to set this width for the `iFrame` element.

This is the code I've wrote:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var width = 300;

    // Get the value of the input width box
    $( 'form#WidgetConfigurator_width' ).keyup(function() {
        alert("should get the innerHTML or text value here");
    });

    if ( width < 180 ) {
        width = 180;
    }

    if ( width > 500 ) {
        width = 500;
    }

    $('iframe#WidgetsContent').attr('width', width);
});
```

The problem is the `alert` is never shown, also if the default value is set for the `iFrame` on first load of the page.
I'm doing this step-by-step, so showing the alert is the first step to know I'm on the right way.

```
<form name="WidgetConfigurator" method="post" action="/widgets" id="WidgetConfigurator" _lpchecked="1">
    <div id="WidgetConfigurator">
        <div>
            <label for="WidgetConfigurator_width">Larghezza del widget</label>
            <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_width" name="WidgetConfigurator[width]">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the code of the `iFrame`:

```
<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1" frameborder="0" height="600"></iframe>
```

**What I want to achieve is the resizing of the `iframe` after the user sets the width in the `input` (the same thing that does Facebook when configuring the [Page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin))**

Any advices on this? Thank you!

Comment: By pressing enter in input, you are submiting `form`. And this is wrong selector: `form#WidgetConfigurator_width`, should be `#WidgetConfigurator_width`

Comment: Yes, I know. But I want to know how to apply editings to the form in a dynamic way. Anyway, I've edited the question removing the part about the `Enter` key press.

Comment: So does it works or not: `$( '#WidgetConfigurator_width' ).keyup(function() {
        alert("should get the innerHTML or text value here");
    });` ???

Comment: No, doesn't work. :( The alert isn't shown.

Comment: Works here... http://jsfiddle.net/rqjhrb3j/  But your posted code doesn't make sense regarding `width` variable outside keyup handler

Comment: Note `$("#WidgetConfigurator_width")` would be better than `$("form #WidgetConfigurator_width")` and I would use  `$("#WidgetConfigurator_width").on('keyup',function(event){event.which...`  to get the key code normalized by jQuery Example fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/d1fk7uem/ that also handles tab out and pasting of values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have wrong selector form#WidgetConfigurator_width it must be
 form #WidgetConfigurator_width and I think you need code like this

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

   
    // Get the value of the input width box
    $( 'form #WidgetConfigurator_width' ).keyup(function() {

       var w=parseInt( $(this).val())
     if ( w< 180 ) {
             w= 180;
         }

       if ( w> 500 ) {
            w= 500;
         }
 
    $('iframe#WidgetContent').width(w)
    });

   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="WidgetConfigurator" method="post" action="/widgets" id="WidgetConfigurator" _lpchecked="1">
    <div id="WidgetConfigurator">
        <div>
            <label for="WidgetConfigurator_width">Larghezza del widget</label>
            <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_width" name="WidgetConfigurator[width]">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1" frameborder="0" height="600"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 3):

First note that you are calling to an iframe which doesn't exist,with the code below:

```
$('iframe#WidgetsContent').attr('width', width);
```

After that in the first line you subject the a form element which has the attribute 'id="widgetConfigurator_width" which doesnt exist too. Try this:

```
$( 'input#WidgetConfigurator_width' ).keyup(function() {
alert("should get the innerHTML or text value here");
});
```

Good Luck

Comment: I don't understand: the `iFame` exists on the page as exists the `input` with id `WidgetConfigurator_width`... What do you mean?

Comment: Ok, the problem were i called the id of the input using form instead of input o.O

Comment: @Aerendir There is no element `form#WidgetConfigurator_width` nor `iframe#WidgetsContent`. Fix it and try again

Comment: form#something subjects to a form with a specific id. you have to use input#something to reach the desired input element.

Answer (score 0):

Possible here is what you are searching:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="resize(event, $(this).val())" id="WidgetConfigurator_width" name="WidgetConfigurator[width]">
```

And the script:

```
var resize = function (e, w) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    $('iframe#WidgetsContent').prop('width', w);
  }
};
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be JQuery in use except for the select of the iFrame... Is it?

Comment: I would NOT be in support this answer which moves code from code to the markup for the event handler code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var width = 300;

 // Get the value of the input width box
 $('#WidgetConfigurator_width' ).on('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
   width = ($(this).val().length) ? $(this).val() : width;
   if ( width < 180 ) {
    width = 180;
   }

   if ( width > 500 ) {
    width = 500;
   }

   $('#WidgetContent').animate({'width': width}, 100); 
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="WidgetConfigurator" method="post" action="/widgets" id="WidgetConfigurator" _lpchecked="1">
    <div id="WidgetConfigurator">
        <div>
            <label for="WidgetConfigurator_width">Larghezza del widget</label>
            <input type="text" id="WidgetConfigurator_width" name="WidgetConfigurator[width]">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<br />
<iframe id="WidgetContent" src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/widget/1" frameborder="0" height="100"></iframe>
```